# How to handle unauthorized bearer token and customize message

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

When I call a client without a bearer token or with an erroneous token, I will get an error 500 server error + in HTML format.

The error is thrown from HttpClientErrorException (spring-web-5.3.7).
Is there an ability to catch a mistake and throw it out in your own format?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

HttpClientErrorException comes with a method (getRawStatusCode) allowing you to know what the problem was (401 was an authentication problem, 404 was a not found ...). You can then catch the exception and handle it differently depending on the status code, for instance throw your own exceptions based on the one you received :

```
try {
    restTemplate.postForObject(url, entity, String.class);
        
} catch (HttpClientErrorException e){
    if(e.getRawStatusCode() == 400)
        throw new BadRequestException(e);
    else if(e.getRawStatusCode() == 401)
        throw new UnauthorizedException(e);
...
}
```

with your exceptions defined like that :

```
@ResponseStatus(value= HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public class BadRequestException extends RuntimeException {
    public BadRequestException(Exception e) {
        super(e);
    }
}
```

With the *@ResponseStatus* annotation, the user will received the error that you linked with the exception and will probably understand what happened.